# Determing how many Bytes a file contains - Assembly

Tags: file, assembly

Im having an assignment that requires me to open a file and do some stuff in it :)

As I was searching on how to read from the file, I reached this website ;its a pretty good and easy Introduction http://stuff.pypt.lt/ggt80x86a/asm6.htm

Here that mate says that I should provide Number of Bytes in CX for Int21H.. But What about if I don't know how many bytes the file conatains??

```
AH = 3Fh
BX = handle
CX = number of bytes to be read
DS:DX = segment:offset of a buffer
```

Is there a way to find out :?

Answer (score 0):

Before calling the function, set CX to the size of the buffer that will receive the data.  When the function returns AX will have the number actually read.  If the file is shorter than CX, then AX < CX.  If it is the same or longer then AX = CX.

Comment: Thats Just a walk-around.. So there's no way to find the exact value :?